# CSS block doesn't scale to 100% with narrow browser

Tags: html, css, browser, width, scale

I have a problem - a container block doesn't scale 100% when my browser is narrower than 100% of the page-width (aka 960px).

Image: http://www.upload.ee/image/1549682/problem.png

```
   /* CONTENT */
div#content {
width:100%;
background-color: #e0e3e3;
}

div#content_wrap {
display: block;
width: 960px;
min-height:200px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}


<div id="content">
    <div id="content_wrap">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you experiencing the problem in?  It seems to work fine in chrome.

Answer (score 1):

add this in your style

```
body{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to fix the problem at all : http://jsfiddle.net/bwcSs/ you can still scroll to the side to see blank space.

Comment: @hughes copy complete code add paste into the notepad then check

Comment: Which browser? Narrow while annoying ads showing? Why are you adding 10px of padding to the body in style.css then to remove it? So many questions... I'm using Chrome and this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

change `width: 100%` to `display: inline-block`.

```
div#content {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #e0e3e3;
}
```

the problem is that `width: 100%` sets the width to 100% of the *parent element*, not the size of the children. To fit a div to the content, use `inline-block` .

Comment: That cancelled the margins somehow and the page isn't centered anymore and the background color only affects the children element-are, but I want it to be full-width.

Comment: Display:inline-block + width 100% did the trick, thanks for your help.